# Is there a diff/patch function/library for varchar field in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to regularly update value of a large varchar field in a PG DB. 
Rather then sending and applying the whole value, I'd like to send only a diff value and update the field via a patch function.
So, can someone pls advise a diff/patch function for PG? 
I'm on a version 9.6

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got:

Sorry for higher version (it's been 2 years)

Install this: https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch

on Ubuntu (18.04), I've installed this packet `sudo apt-get install postgresql-plpython3-10`

then in postgres:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpython3u;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS pyhton_patch;
CREATE FUNCTION pyhton_patch(incoming_body TEXT, old TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS $$

from diff_match_patch import diff_match_patch
new_body = ''
old_body = old

try:
        dmp = diff_match_patch()
        patch = dmp.patch_fromText(incoming_body)
        if patch is not None and len(patch):
                new_body, _ = dmp.patch_apply(patch, old_body)
        else:
                new_body = incoming_body
except ValueError as e:
        new_body = incoming_body
except Exception as ex:
        new_body = incoming_body

return new_body

$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;



SELECT * FROM pyhton_patch('@@ -1 +1 @@
-aaa
+aaba'::TEXT, 'aaa'::TEXT);
```